# how can i get an array from an another array

Tags: php, arrays

someone help me.. i just stucked and cant get any idea how too do it.

Source array:

```
  ["data"] => array(10) {
      ["type"] => string(10) "controller"
      ["name"] => string(3) "eg1"
      ["description"] => string(5) "desc1"
      ["type2"] => string(8) "function"
      ["name2"] => string(2) "c2"
      ["controller2"] => string(4) "welcome"
      ["description2"] => string(6) "desc 2"
      ["type3"] => string(10) "controller"
      ["name3"] => string(2) "c3"
      ["description3"] => string(8) "c3 descr"
    }
```

from the above array how can i get new array like:

```
   array(
     array(
       'type' => 'controller',
       'name' => 'eg1',
       'description' => 'desc1'
     ),
      array(
       'type' => 'function',
       'controller' => 'welcome',
       'name' => 'c2',
       'description' => 'desc 2'
     ),
     array(
       'type' => 'controller',
       'name' => 'eg1',
       'description' => 'desc1'
     ),
     array(
       'type' => 'controller',
       'name' => 'c3',
       'description' => 'c3 descr'
     )
   );
```

data is submitted through a https://github.com/tristandenyer/Clone-section-of-form-using-jQuery

thanks for help

Comment: That's not an associative array. It's a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: also, kind of hard to help if you don't give us the real array. a solution that works for your given array might not work for the real data.

Comment: i have edited my question with real data as well as specifically what i need.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an associative array, it's just a 2-dimensional array containing the elements of the original array in groups of 3. You can use [`array_chunk`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.array-chunk.php) for this.

```
$new_array = array_chunk($array, 3);
```

Comment: Didn't actually know that was a function :) you learn something every day